# Need to fetch the password using Regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

```
a= <<EOF

Password 

: 

7UV1ceFQ (You will be asked to change this after logging in for the first time) 

EOF
```

I need to extract the value "7UV1ceFQ" using regular expression, I have tried using '/Password  :  7UV1ceFQ/ but it's not working, I think it's because next line character is included, Can anyone please suggest me to exact this value?

Comment: I don't understand why my question is not clear, I am saying that "7UV1ceFQ " value has to be extracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
▶ a[/^\S+(?=\s\(You will be)/]
#⇒ "7UV1ceFQ"
```

The regular expression above reads as:

- starting with a new line start     `^`
- get all non-space symbols greedy   `\S+`
- until the [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)       `(?=\s\(You will be)`

Comment: you're our regexp's king :D

Comment: hi Ursus, Can you please explain me the above regular expression you have written?

Comment: I am by no means Ursus, but since I am an author, I will provide an explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I was about to use your name, I accidentally used his name. Thanks.